# Remove /sitecore from the URLs

Tags: url, sitecore

I need to remove "/sitecore" from URLs because when I navigate to appropriate sites (www.site_name/sitecore) I will get empty page with no layout. I would like to ask you

1) Is good option to use redirect to solve my problem ?

2) Can this redirection of the "/sitecore" caused problems ? I found that in sites definition of my web config I have a lot of site definition like this:
site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell ... where "/sitecore" is part of some other paths so I am not sure.

I appreciate your help. Thx

Comment: What do you mean with : I found that in sites definition of my web config I have a lot of site definition like this: "  ?

Comment: What is exactly your site definition?

Comment: As part of my sites configuration I have also sitecore configuration like: <site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true"/>

Comment: Those site definitions are required by the system to operate, esp in CM environment. You can lock these down in CD environment if needed.

Comment: This is what I meant so if I redirect sites in pattern: www.site_name/sitecore to www.site_name if this can caused some problems ? Or can I used some better solution

Comment: Yes it's possible but there are some settings which would need to be updated to avoid errors, e.g. `KeepAlive`, `ItemNotFoundUrl` and possibly others if you other using modules (EXM for example)

Comment: I would suggest you read this blog post: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/have_sitecore_content_in_your_urls_time_to_fix_it/